# How to access the viewstate of a programmatically added UserControl during page init?

Tags: asp.net, viewstate

I have a set of programmatically added user controls on the page (they are created and added during the Init event of the main page). Each of these control programmatically add buttons during his own Init event.
*(So it's "two levels" of dynamically created controls. Don't know if it matters.)*

But **I need to access the viewstate while creating those buttons** (I use the viewstate to remember user data).

```
protected void Page_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // I need my ViewState right now !
    Button myButton = new Button();
    myButton.Text = "Click me";
    myButton.Command += new CommandEventHandler(myCommandHandler);
    myButton.CommandName = "Delete";
    myButton.ID = "myButtonID";
    myPlaceholder.Controls.Add(myButton);
}
```

I understood that the viewstate isn't available during the Init event. But buttons don't fire their events (OnClick, etc.) if they are created after the Init.

- How to create dynamic controls **and** access the viewstate at the same time ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can. Not ideal but I would put the user data in the `Session` in this instance. Dynamic controls are difficult to work with and I think this is one of the trade offs. ViewState loads after `Page_Init` - this [forum post](http://www.velocityreviews.com/forums/t90964-can-i-get-viewstate-data-during-page-oninit.html) confirms

Another option might be to store the information in your own hidden fields. These will become available in the `Request.Form` collection during postback and will be available. Of course if you make them `runat="server"` (which you will probably have to) the framework will append all the naming container ids to the name so you will have to be a bit clever when digging them out. It's going to get a bit hacky though so I would be tempted to stick to the Session

Someone else might know different of course.

Comment: Thank you. It seems to work when using hidden fields and reading their content with `Request.Form`. I still don't understand why dynamic controls aren't easier to work with. I'll try to avoid them as much as I can ^^